# AngularJs get data from $http before controller init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple angularjs application, in which I want to run a slider and the slider elements come from $http request.

Here is the code for reference:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("myapp", []);  

mainApp.run(['$rootScope', '$http',
    function($rootScope, $http) {
$http.post('process.php?ajax_type=getChild').success(function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                console.log(data.child);  // data received...
                $rootScope.categories = data.child;
            }
        });
}]);

mainApp.controller('gridChildController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
console.log($rootScope.categories);  // this is also null....
$scope.brands = $rootScope.categories;
    $scope.finished = function(){
        jQuery('.brand_slider').iosSlider({
            desktopClickDrag: true, 
            snapToChildren: true, 
            infiniteSlider: false, 
            navNextSelector: '.brands-next', 
            navPrevSelector: '.brands-prev', 
            lastSlideOffset: 3,
            onSlideChange: function (args) {

            } 
        });
    };
});
```

Here is code of the template file:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="gridChildController" class="brand_slider" >
   <div class='slider'>
      <div class="slide col-md-5ths col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center" ng-repeat="x in brands" ng-init="$last && finished()">
          <a href="{{x.link}}"><img class="img-responsive center-block" ng-src="{{x.image}}" title="{{x.title}}" alt="{{x.title}}"></a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

When I run this code, I get the data from the $http but ng-repeat doesn't work, and in the controller I get data null.

Comment: Use resolve if you're using angular routing.

Comment: You're not injecting `$rootScope` in your controller and you're not initializing the controller in your view.

Comment: @Dieterg Absolutely I made some mistake in code copy paste. Thank you, check it I have edit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put something on `$rootScope` it will be also available on the child scopes. So you can bind straight to `categories` (no need to copy it to `$scope.brands`):

```
ng-repeat="x in categories"
```